# Compare 2 videos automatically

Tags: video, software-recommendation

I have 2 videos that are expected to be the same, but in some periods of time they may differ by additional elements shown above the video. Also video is reencoded, so some minor differences are possible. I want to run some program that will compare these videos and output me list of time slots where videos are different enough. What program should I use?

Note that I'm not interested in visual side-by-side comparison tool, I need the tool that will output time slots only without additional user interaction.